# Struggling with required field with PHP form

Tags: php, required-field

This is my first time using php and I haven't a clue what I'm doing. I've taken this template and coded a html form to go with it, it all works except that there's no required fields so it can send a blank email if you click submit. I'd like it to have an error message come up when the 'name' and 'email' and 'message' inputs are empty. Can anyone help?

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "joejlomax@gmail.com";
$EmailTo = "joejlomax@gmail.com";
$Subject = "T/V/C Inquiry";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 


// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.php\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.php\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: Start by using `if (isset($your_variable) && ($your_variable != ''))` ?

Comment: Next step would be to make sure that the email address is valid.http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `empty` to check if the variable is.. empty.

```
$validationOK = true;
if(empty($Name) OR empty($Tel) OR empty($Email) OR empty($Message)) {
    $validationOK = false;
}
if (!$validationOK) {
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.php\">";
    exit;
}
```